# Enabling zoom when on gallery fullscreen

Tags: gallery, zoom

How can I get the zoom effect on a gallery product page to show when I am in full screen mode? I am using Magento 2.3.4 enterprise.

[image]

This is what I have in myTheme/etc/view.xml file.

```
<vars module="Magento_Catalog">
    <!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
    <var name="gallery">
        <var name="nav">dots</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
        <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
        <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
        <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
        <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
        <var name="allowfullscreen">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
        <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
        <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides arrows(true/false) -->
        <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
        <var name="transition">
            <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
            <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
        </var>
        <var name="fullscreen">
            <var name="nav">dots</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview in fullscreen (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title in fullscreen(true/false) -->
            <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in fullscreen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
            <var name="navarrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides arrows(true/false) -->
            <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
            <var name="transition">
                <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>

    <var name="magnifier">
        <var name="fullscreenzoom">5</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
        <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
        <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
        <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
        <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
        <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that activates zoom (hover/click) -->
        <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
    </var>
```

Comment: <var name="magnifier"> is  enable in view.xml

Comment: <var name="enabled">false</var> Only gets me the magnifier on regular product detail page. Not when I am looking at it full screen.

Answer (score 0):

The icons actually come by cropping a weird background which contain all the icons, located here - `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/gallery/gallery.png` so you will have to adjust background-size, background-position and width and height of following elements to get your desired size of icons. Adjust your code as follows (done for + icon)

```
.fotorama__fullscreen .fotorama__zoom-in {
    background-position: 0 0 !important;
    background-size: 126px;
    top: 0;
}

fotorama__zoom-in.zoom-in-loaded {
    height: 16%;
    width: 4%;
}
```

check this useful link :- **[Magento 2 : How reduce size of fotoroma gallery icons on product detail page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238499/magento-2-how-reduce-size-of-fotoroma-gallery-icons-on-product-detail-page)**

Hope this help you

Thanks...